# Number pattern or some logic?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, pattern-recognition

[image]

I spent an hour attempting to solve this but couldn't find any particular pattern in which the numbers are arranged.  I asked my teachers but none of them could solve it.

The answer is

> 8

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 2):

First row + Third row = Second row + Fourth row

6849 + 4675 = 8659 + 2865

5777 + 5658 = 9299 + 2136

4271 + 6005 = 4595 + 5681

3284 + ?052 = 4492 + 6844